# How to assign a lamba expression event to another event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, combobox, textbox

I am dinamically defining a wpf window with some textboxes and checkboxes programmatically defined.
After having added them I want to check if all textboxes and checkboxes are filled.
To do that for the textboxes I have the lamda expression defined event:

```
var mw = new MyWindow();
mw.KeyDown += (senderEvent, args) =>
{
  cycle on all windows and when it's a TEXTBOX or a COMBOBOX analyze if it's empty or not.
  That is a lot of code which I wouldn't not replicate nor use an external routine
}
```

but how can I associate the same code to be fired also when combobox are closed??
The best would be to change the code above to (pseudocode):

```
mw.AllEvents += (senderEvent, args) =>{ ... }
```

or

```
mw.KeyDown && mw.ComboBoxClose += (senderEvent, args) =>{ ... }
```

but that doesn't make sense since a window has not comboboxclose event

either this or when defining all the comboboxes to be able to do something like:

```
newComboBox.ComboBoxClosed +=  (senderEvent, args) =>{ ...clone from mw.KeyDown }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, they're different types of delegate.

DropDownClosed is an EventHandler while KeyDown is an KeyEventHandler, so when you write your lambda, args is type EventArgs in one and KeyEventArgs in other, they're just infering it's type from the assignation.

If both of them where EventHandlers or KeyEventHandlers then you can save it to a variable and assign that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The method signatures are different, so you can't do exactly that.  However, you can point all your lambdas toward a common method:

```
private void MyHandler()
{
    //bulk of the work
} 

//....
mw.KeyDown += (s,e) => MyHandler();
mw.ComboBoxClose += (s,e) => MyHandler();
```

If you need the EventArgs you could pass it through and do some sort of switch on the type in `MyHandler`

Comment: A window is not a comboBox so it has no mw.ComboBoxClose Event!

Comment: Oh I see.  You'll have to manually pass up / re-raise your ComboBoxClose from `MyWindow`.  That's pretty messy